# Why do I get Client authentication failed on XAMPP server and Linux server?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, xampp

I'm trying to make a POST request using CURL.
Using Postman and on my local machine using IIS there is no error but on XAMPP server and Linux server with CA certificate I get:

```
{"error":"OAUth Error","status":401,"message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

The code look like this:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.timewave.se/v3/oauth/token',
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('client_id' => '1','client_secret' => 'abc........abc','grant_type' => 'client_credentials'),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Why do I get 'Client authentication failed' on XAMPP server and Linux server?

Comment: Well, what do the http server's error log files reveal what the cause for that is?

Comment: I think this is what's relevant from error.log file: [Fri Sep 16 10:12:29.047287 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 10452:tid 432] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Sep 16 10:12:29.047287 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 10452:tid 432] AH01909: blomquist.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Kinsta has a [KB article](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-server-name/) dedicated to that error message and XAMPP which seems very promising

Comment: Nope, that certificate issue is _not_ responsible for an authentication issue.

Comment: @arkascha Not true. The auth token that is returned in the body of the HTTPS response must be kept secure. That is a good reason to reject the Auth request. You are correct, but it is up to Timewave what the error message will be. There is nothing else wrong with the request unless there is a typo. The 401 OAuth error means The confirmation string does not correspond to the token.  That is not a valid response because the Auth request does not use a token, it is requesting a token.  I'm going with a CA issue or typo which is unlikely because because the code worked it Postman.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is curl made a request and the server responded.

The most likely suspect is a problem with the HTTPS CA Certificate.
Your curl post data looks good.
Their example curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.timewave.nu/v3/oauth/token' \
--form 'client_id="5"' \
--form 'client_secret="0zbrotKJAGaLGKhuGC0LJLVdkR7Z4lKuqWIxoMqI"' \
--form 'grant_type="client_credentials"'
```

You have the --location option covered with:

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
```

And using an array for the post data, guaranties the content type will be "form" data.
The only thing (other than SSL) I could see that may get this response is a typo in the post data.

But there are a few other things that should be fixed.

POST is not a valid parameter for `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`
Although  it may still work. 
The PHP manual lists the valid parameters, and POST is not one of them.
You should use: `CURLOPT_POST=>true,`

This brings up another issue.  Because the auth credentials must be kept secure you very likely cannot use `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,`.

You will likely need the curl_set_opt`URLOPT_CAINFO` option, or a certificate directory can be specified with the `CURLOPT_CAPATH`

You should look at your Request Header.
You may see somethng wrong.
Add `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true`

Then after the `curl_exec($curl);`

```
echo '<pre>' . curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

Or look at all the details of the request and response including the request header.

```
$info = var_export(curl_getinfo($curl),true);
echo "<pre>$info";
```

The response header should look like this:

```
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 06:37:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, private
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for all response
I found the issue in error.log

```
[Mon Jun 20 11:32:38.031690 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 12036:tid 388] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Edited file on local server
..\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-server-name/

```
ServerName www.example.com:443
```

to

```
ServerName localhost
```

For some reason it works on live Linux server without any modification